# If $\log_{12} 18=a$ and $\log_{24} 54=b$ prove that $ab+5(a-b)=1$

Tags: logarithms

First I've written $\log_{12} 18=a$ in terms of base 24 and then did the same to $\log_{24} 54=b$ and written it in terms of base 12. That gave me a value of $a=\frac{\log_{24} 2+2\log_{24} 3} {2\log_{24} 2+\log_{24} 3}$

I did the same thing with $b$ and put the values of $a$ and $b$ in $ab+5(a-b)=1$

now how do I find the common denominator and simplify the equation and prove it?

Comment: It's not $ab-5(a-b)$, in fact it's $ab+5(a-b)$, as seen here : [$X = \log_{12} 18$ and $Y= \log_{24} 54$. Find $XY + 5(X - Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165667/x-log-12-18-and-y-log-24-54-find-xy-5x-y)

Comment: Then the question in my book might be wrong hence I can't seem to solve it. Thanks.